# Make SQLite journal files hidden

Tags: sqlite, hidden-files

I want to use SQLite with TRUNCATE journal mode (`PRAGMA journal_mode = TRUNCATE`), but I don't want all these `-journal` files to be visible to the normal users. I want them to behave like the `.tmp` files in Ms Word (hidden).

Is there some way to make them hidden, at least in Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [set the "hidden" attribute bit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365535.aspx) on the `-journal` file, SQLite will keep it. (As long as nobody ever uses the `DELETE` journal mode on that database.)